# heroku current transaction is aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small free app running on heroku.

intermittently the app stops working and displays the default heroku error page on the screen.  when I check the logs I see the following:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
>   (PGError: ERROR:  current transaction
>   is aborted, commands ignored until end
>   of transaction block : SELECT * FROM
>   "users" WHERE ("users"."password" =
>   E'' AND "users"."userid" = E'')  LIMIT
>   1):   app/models/user.rb:5:in
>   `authenticate'
>
>   app/controllers/admin_controller.rb:6:in`
>   login'

in my controller I am just doing following:

```
user = User.authenticate(params[:storeid], params[:password])
```

and in User model:

```
  def self.authenticate(userid, password)
    user = self.find_by_userid_and_password(userid, password)
    user
  end
```

The error messages leads me to believe that some connections are left hanging and are never closed. Is this ever a case in a ruby app?

In my app there are also many places where I am using find_by_sql. does that require us to explicitly close connections?

Like this:

```
@sqlstmmt1 = "INSERT INTO addresses (\"line1\", \"line2\", city, state, zip, county) VALUES ('" + params[:line1] + "', '"+ params[:line2] + "', '"+params[:city]+ "', '" + params[:state] + "', '" + params[:zip]+ "', '" + params[:county]+"')"
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.connection();
sql.begin_db_transaction
```

Answer (score 0):

I get that error due to what I think is when trying to insert utf-8 characters, so I guess your password could have exotic characters. BTW: You should escape the sql-string you use, embedding params[:anything] is baaaad.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting a similar error and this bit of Rails documentation helped:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods

> Warning: one should not catch ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
>   exceptions inside a transaction block. ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
>   exceptions indicate that an error occurred at the database level, for
>   example when a unique constraint is violated. On some database
>   systems, such as PostgreSQL, database errors inside a transaction
>   cause the entire transaction to become unusable until it’s restarted
>   from the beginning. Here is an example which demonstrates the problem:

...

Answer (score 0):

I just relaunched the application and everything goes back right

```
heroku restart
```

Hope it will help!